# ServiceStack AutoQuery Is Null for Asp.Net.Core and NullReferenceException thrown at CreateQuery

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I've done the Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100 }); and used it in startup Configure Method.

[image]

[image]

This is dto inherites QueryDb

[image]

I keep encountering AutoQuery is null and NullReferenceException thrown at AutoQuery.CreateQuery() Method. And CallStacks can not show ExternalCodes. I have no ideas where it gone wrong by referring to TechStacks Project.

[image]

[image]

The project references ServiceStack.Core 5.7.0

I'm able to get AutoQuery by using the below code.

```
var autoquery = TryResolve<IAutoQueryDb>()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of your code samples show the 3 important things required for AutoQuery, the `AutoQueryFeature` plugin registration in your AppHost’s `Configure()`, the definition of your Service class that implements the `Service` base class, the `public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }` public property.

If they’re configured correctly the IAutoQueryDb dependency should be injected.

Comment: the plugin AutoQueryFeature in AppHost Configure and the inherits ServiceStack.Service and  public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; } are there. I've updated the screenshots. I do not know where it goes wrong, AutoQuery is still null.

Comment: Can't identify the issue from the screenshots, can you try seeing if you can resolve it from the IOC directly, e.g. `var autoquery = TryResolve<IAutoQueryDb>()`. Note: your DefaultContentType is invalid, if you want JSON it should instead be: `DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json`.

Comment: Thanks @mythz `var autoquery = TryResolve<IAutoQueryDb>()` is working. Noted with `DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json`. Why I can't use the `public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }` public property. I updated the screenshot above. is there anyway to troubleshoot ?

Comment: It appears something is preventing (or overriding) the IoC property injection, not identifiable from just this description. If you can put together a stand-alone repro on GitHub using ServiceStack v5.9 I can take a look.

Comment: I'm using ServiceStack.Core v5.7.0 will it be the cause ? because I need to renew my license if using ServiceStack v5.9.

Comment: You won’t need a license for the repro, but need to confirm that’s it an issue with the latest version

Comment: BTW why are you using ServiceStack.Core, are you using ASP.NET Core on the .NET Framework?

Comment: Thanks @mythz. I will give a try for the latest assembly. I'm using asp.net core. not .NET Framework. So I instinctively thought the ServiceStack.Core should be the right assembly. So I should change to ServiceStack ?

Comment: Yes, the .Core packages is only for [ASP.NET Core on the .NET Framework](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) use the normal packages for .NET Core, this could be the issue if you’re mixing packages

Comment: NullReferenceException thrown at AutoQuery.CreateQuery() Method. it is still the same even I uses servicestack 5.9.0.

Comment: Ok post a stand-alone repro on GitHub and I’ll take a look

Comment: I spent some time doing a repro. but it turns out totally fine. Finally I find out the autoquery problem associates with `services.AddSingleton<QueueService>();services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AuditService>();` after I commented out the IHostedService, AutoQuery is working fine.